# Using changeset number in a java program

Tags: java, ant, mercurial, changeset

I am using Mercurial HG for versioning my projects. To keep my version-number in my build/compiled programs uptodate I am using this approach. I've modified the build.xml to override a predefined target.

```
<target name="-pre-compile">
    <!-- getting the version in a fancy format -->
    <exec executable="hg" outputproperty="version.mercurial">
       <arg value="parent"/>
       <arg value="--template"/>
       <arg value="{latesttag}.{rev}-{branch}-{node|short}"/>
    </exec>
    <echo level="warning">Version ${version.mercurial}</echo>
    <manifest file="${manifest.file}" mode="update">
       <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${version.mercurial}"/>
   </manifest>
</target>
```

** note `hg.exe` is in my classpath.

To retrieve the version property I use the following code snippet in my mainclass

```
String version = Main.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

When I build my project and run it with this `java -jar myproject.jar` the version number is correct and from that point everything is fine.

But when I run it in my IDE the version string ist `null`, so the manifest file isn't read.
So this makes me thinking if this approach is valid or is there another, even a simpler way to keep the version number uptodate?

EDIT: Is there a more sophisticated way to include the version number into your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the `output` attribute to Ant's `<exec ..>` task to write a properties file instead.  Then you can use the `<properties file="...">` method to read it in Ant, and can load it like a normal properties file when running in your IDE.

Good for you for not using the KeywordsExtension for this.  It's a horrible solution in a DVCS world.